# Awk get 2 columns and count repeated values in new column

Tags: linux, awk

The following script is made to create a new csv getting the gender and state columns and counting the repeated values and grouping them by states, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly as the new csv I get is empty.
Code

```
gawk -f scrt.awk ml1.csv > ml2.csv
```

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -F
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    FNR>1 { counts[$12 OFS $9]++ }
    END   { for (i in counts) print i,counts[i] }
```

Input csv

```
  nw,d,nm,year,date,mns,arm,age,gender,rc,city,state,sg
    x,x,pac,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Male,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ces,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Female,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ret,2015,2015-01-06,sur,ml apon,53,Male,A,Shelton,OR,x
    x,x,set,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,47,Male,W,Aloha,OR,x
    x,x,wem,2015,2015-01-04,sur,ml apon,32,Male,W,San Francisco,CA,x
```

Expected output

```
state,gender,count
WA,Male,1
WA,Female,1
OR,Male,2
CA,Male,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I did run following input

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR>1 { counts[$12 OFS $9]++ }
END   { for (i in counts) print i,counts[i] }
```

using gawk 4.2.1 code

```
  nw,d,nm,year,date,mns,arm,age,gender,rc,city,state,sg
    x,x,pac,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Male,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ces,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Female,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ret,2015,2015-01-06,sur,ml apon,53,Male,A,Shelton,OR,x
    x,x,set,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,47,Male,W,Aloha,OR,x
    x,x,wem,2015,2015-01-04,sur,ml apon,32,Male,W,San Francisco,CA,x
```

and got output

```
CA,Male,1
WA,Male,1
OR,Male,2
WA,Female,1
```

which is equivalnet to desired

```
WA,Male,1
WA,Female,1
OR,Male,2
CA,Male,1
```

when you ignore order of lines. If you wish to traverse array in certain order in GNU `AWK` then set `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to one of [available predefined orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) inside `BEGIN` or if none suits your needs prepare [own comparison function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html)

Comment: When I try to make the code inside the awk script and execute it the way I explained I continue having the same problem, could you tell me how to make it work inside the .awk script

Comment: @krlm what problem, do you get any description why it refuses to work?

Comment: I have created a scrip.awk and entered the code as you have given me, and when I run the script with the command the file to which I redirect my output is totally empty. How can I run the code inside a script with the command gawk -f scr.awk 1.csv>2.csv

Comment: @krim what version of GNU `AWK` are you using, that is what is output when you do `gawk --version`

Comment: GNU Awk 5.0.1 API 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2 GNU MP 6.2.0)

Comment: @krlm please try doing following and write what was result `gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR>1{counts[$12 OFS $9]++}END{for(i in counts)print i,counts[i]}' ml1.csv`

Comment: That way works on the linux terminal, how could I make that inside the script to make it work.

Comment: @krlm created file with two lines, 1st one `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f` 2nd one `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR>1{counts[$12 OFS $9]++}END{for(i in counts)print i,counts[i]}` and name it say `script.awk` make it executable `chmod u+x script.awk` then use it as follows `./script.awk ml1.csv`